# TypeError when trying to call function inside function with **kwargs?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm confused about why this error is occurring:

> TypeError: func1() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)

The code is as follows:

```
def func1(**kwargs):
    if kwargs['dog'] != 2:
        return False
    return True

def func2(**kwargs):
    if kwargs['cat'] != 3:
        return False
    return True

def func3(*listOfFuncs, **extraArgs):
    for func in listOfFuncs:
        if func(extraArgs) == False:
            print 'break'
            break
        print 'continue'
        continue

func3(func1, func2, dog=2, cat=1)
```

I'm trying to pass function names as arguments to func3. I also want to pass both 'cat' and 'dog' keyword arguments to both func1 and func2 when they are called in fun3 but only use a single keyword argument in each of those functions?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The error you've posted can't possibly match up to the code, there's no `testy` anywhere

Comment: I'm sorry. I rewrote the code to make it easier to read on stack overflow but forgot to update error message. It has been corrected.

Comment: If you satisfied with my solution, then please mark the answer as useful (Upvote) and this may helpfull for other users also. This way we can manage the good habit of stack overflow.

Comment: No problem. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the **kwargs args at the time of function call.

I have just reviewed your code. Please try following

```
def func1(**kwargs):
    if kwargs['dog'] != 2:
        return False
    return True

def func2(**kwargs):
    if kwargs['cat'] != 3:
        return False
    return True

def func3(*listOfFuncs, **extraArgs):
    print 
    for func in listOfFuncs:
        if func(**extraArgs) == False:
            print 'break'
            break
        print 'continue'
        continue

func3(func1, func2, dog=2, cat=1)
```

Output :

```
continue
break
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Was really struggling to work it out!

Comment: It's my pleasure. I'm always happy to help.